# Terminology Question

Tags: radiator, fluid

I just got back from getting my car serviced and they said that my radiator fluid is "35 below 0" on the service report they gave back. What does this mean? Thanks!

Comment: The temperature at which your coolant would freeze, i.e. -35°F (assuming you're in the U.S.)?

Comment: That's what I figured, but he kinda pointed that out on the whole list that I got back, so I didn't know if it meant something else.

Comment: -35F is essentially what you get with an exact 50:50 mix.  Its not clear here did they change it or check it?  (Should be obvious from how much they billed).

Comment: So most people realize, -35F is -37C ... there's not much difference around that part of the scale with both equalizing at -40. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

It means that your coolant (radiator fluid) can withstand temperature as low as -35 (assuming Ferandhiet).

Coolant is not just water. It includes ethylene glycol to reduce the coolants ability to boil or freeze. Frozen coolant can cause damage to engines and cooling system from the expansion during the freezing process. This is strong enough to crack engine blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like they are referring to the freeze point of the coolant(radiator fluid).  Some places will dip a little test strip (kind of like those swimming pool strips to check pH) that declares at what temperature the coolant would freeze at in cold conditions as we approach the winter season.  In other words, your coolant's freeze point is -35 Fahrenheit, which sounds about normal.